# Replace line in file with NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am trying to replace line in my config file using nsis, based on the searched results.
I have following functions included in my nsis file

To search for string:

```
Function SearchInFile
 

    ; HOW USE
    ; FileOpen $1 'C:\WINNT\system32\drivers\etc\services' r
    ; Push $handle  ; handle of file (open in 'a' or 'r' mode)
    ; Push '#'      ; comments delimiter (All symbols more to the right 
    ;               ; are ignored)
    ; Push 'gds_db' ; sample of search
    ;               ; push '' if comment_symbol are not defined
    ; Push 'no'     ; search mode. If 'begin' to search only from the 
    ;               ; beginning of string
    ; Call SearchInFile
    ; Pop $0        ; Result of search: yes/no 
    ;
     
    Exch $3 ; search mode 
    Exch 3 
    Exch $2 ; file handle 
    Exch 2 
    Exch $1 ; comments delimiter 
    Exch 
    Exch $0 ; search sample
    Exch 3
    Exch
    Exch 2
    Exch
     
    Push $4 ; string from file
    Push $5 ; length of string 
    Push $6 ; not used
    Push $7 ; search result
    Push $8 ; not used
    Push $9 ; not used
    Push $R0 ;length of the search sample
    Push $R1 ;length of the comment symbol
    Push $R2 ;tmp
     
    ClearErrors
    StrLen $5 $0
    StrCpy $7 no
     
    StrLen $R0 $0
    StrLen $R1 $1
     
    lbl_SearchInFile_loop:
    FileRead $2 $4
    IfErrors lbl_SearchInFile_done
     
    StrCmp $3 'begin' lbl_SearchFromBeginOnly lbl_SearchInString_loop
     
    lbl_SearchFromBeginOnly:
    StrLen $5 $4
    StrCpy $R2 $4 $R0                                
    StrCmp $R2 $0 lbl_SampleIsFound lbl_SearchInFile_loop
     
    lbl_SearchInString_loop:
    StrCmp "" $4  lbl_SearchInFile_loop
    StrLen $5 $4 
    StrCmp "" $1  lbl_SearchSampleCont  ; search for the comments delimiter
    StrCpy $R2 $4 $R1
    StrCmp $R2 $1 lbl_SearchInFile_loop
     
    lbl_SearchSampleCont:   
    StrCpy $R2 $4 $R0                     ; search as such the sample
    StrCmp $R2 $0 lbl_SampleIsFound
    IntOp $5 $5 - 1      ; cut a char at the left and continue search
    StrCpy $4 $4 $5 1 
    Goto lbl_SearchInString_loop
     
    lbl_SampleIsFound:
    StrCpy $7 yes
     
    lbl_SearchInFile_done:
      StrCpy $0 $7
     
    Pop $R2
    Pop $R1
    Pop $R0
    Pop $9
    Pop $8
    Pop $7
    Pop $6
    Pop $5
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1 
    Exch $0 ;output yes/no
     
    FunctionEnd
```

To replace line

```
Function ReplaceLineStr
 Exch $R0 ; string to replace that whole line with
 Exch
 Exch $R1 ; string that line should start with
 Exch
 Exch 2
 Exch $R2 ; file
 Push $R3 ; file handle
 Push $R4 ; temp file
 Push $R5 ; temp file handle
 Push $R6 ; global
 Push $R7 ; input string length
 Push $R8 ; line string length
 Push $R9 ; global
 
  StrLen $R7 $R1
 
  GetTempFileName $R4
 
  FileOpen $R5 $R4 w
  FileOpen $R3 $R2 r
 
  ReadLoop:
  ClearErrors
   FileRead $R3 $R6
    IfErrors Done
 
   StrLen $R8 $R6
   StrCpy $R9 $R6 $R7 -$R8
   StrCmp $R9 $R1 0 +3
 
    FileWrite $R5 "$R0$\r$\n"
    Goto ReadLoop
 
    FileWrite $R5 $R6
    Goto ReadLoop
 
  Done:
 
  FileClose $R3
  FileClose $R5
 
  SetDetailsPrint none
   Delete $R2
   Rename $R4 $R2
  SetDetailsPrint both
 
 Pop $R9
 Pop $R8
 Pop $R7
 Pop $R6
 Pop $R5
 Pop $R4
 Pop $R3
 Pop $R2
 Pop $R1
 Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
```

Now, my instllation part looks as below

```
    DetailPrint "Agent already installed, will upgrade"
    DetailPrint "Reading current config"
    FileOpen $0 'pathTofile' r ;
    Push $0 ;
    Push '' ;
    Push 'string1' ;
    Push 'no' ;
   Call SearchInFile
    Pop $0
    ${If} $0 != yes
        DetailPrint ",String1 not found in config. Continuing"
    ${Else}
        DetailPrint "Updating config"
        Push "pathTofile" ;
        Push "foo" ;
        Push "foo string3,string4" ;
       Call ReplaceLineStr
    ${EndIf}
```

Problem is that when it goes to Else statement, than nothing happens - line is not replaced

When running following, without the search Function, it does the replacement. Am I missing something here ?

```
    DetailPrint "Agent already installed, will upgrade"
    DetailPrint "Reading current config"
    DetailPrint "Updating config"
    Push "pathTofile" ;
    Push "foo" ;
    Push "foo string3,string4" ;
   Call ReplaceLineStr
```

Comment: What does the file you want to edit look like?